# Identifying SMD component

Tags: identification, components

I have some case with finding part number of smd chip. But I don't see any information about them.I have checked on s-manuals. Please help me identify them.

1. -HA SOT-25 it's voltage detector or current sense.

[image: -HA SOT-25]

2. !43NX SOT-23. I think it's mosfet or transistor but I'm not sure

[image]

These component from AC-DC convert board. I don't see label or brand on this board. Customer sent and asked checking component.

Comment: Do you know any more about what the 43NX part does? Please don't answer here in the comment section. Add the information to your question. I will delete this comment later (if I remember) => I think it's mosfer or transistor. I saw exclamation mark (!) on 2N7002 On Semiconductors brand. But can't see information about 43N or 43NX

Answer (score 2):

The HA is probably a [TC7SH14F](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/product/general-purpose-logic-ics/detail.TC7SH14F.html).

Not sure about the !43NX. It may be a TL431 if it is connected closely to an optoisolator. A photo showing the surrounding components would help.

Comment: Dear Sir, 
Thank you very much. I have checked HA code but I don't see the hyphen before HA from original package. Is it depended on date code ?
Not sure about the !43NX. It may be a TL431 if it is connected closely to an optoisolator. A photo showing the surrounding components would help => I will upload again.